# Is there any English reference for the paper 'Darstellungstheorie von Schur-Algebren' written by Fredrich Roesler?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Now I'm reading the paper of Friedrich Roesler on the representation theory of Schur-Rings with the title '**Darstellungstheorie von Schur-Algebren**' (Math Z 1972).

My goal is to understand algebraic theory of the Schur-rings used in the paper of John Karlof '**The Subclass Algebra Associated with a Finite Group and Subgroup**'

Is there any English reference for the paper of Friedrich Roesler?

Thank you in advance!

By the way, I'm finding the thesis of Andrew F. Misseldine 'Algebraic and Combinatorial Properties of Schur Rings over Cyclic Groups' very helpful and organized. But I'm not sure yet whether the work of Friedrich Roesler is covered in the thesis or not. The paper is not cited in the reference.

Comment: For a start, you can dump the paper into Google Translate.  The outcome is not perfect  but the advantage is  that you will read the paper with much more carefully than usual.  I did this a couple of times.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thank you very much for your suggestion!